# .htaccess rewrite multiple urls without redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

Ok so i have urls like these demo1.domain.net, demo2.domain.net, demo3.domain.net and all needs to show the contents of a subfolder like this example
demo1.domain.net will show the contents of domain.net/websites/demo1
i need to do it in a way that all the domains like $whatever.domain.net into domain.net/websites/$whatever.domain.net, i already enabled wildcard dns, and i cant seem to fiqure it out, please keep in mind i dont want it to redirect.

Here is what i tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?[^.]+\.domain\.net.*$
RewriteRule /websites/$1 [L]
```

I just get the main page of domain.net with this.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websites/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+\.domain\.net.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /websites/%2/$1 [L]
```

Note that this will only work if the all the **demo*.domain.net** point to the same document root as the main domain (**domain.net**).

Comment: They all do point to the main root folder but this doesn't work for me i get Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @user2314536 forgot to add an exclusion condition

Comment: Hey i i made a huge mistake sorry you guys its suppose to be $whatever.domain.net into domain.net/websites/$whatever.domain.net

Comment: This gives the me the right thing but with a redirect RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)whmcs-templates\.net$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.whmcs-templates\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://whmcs-templates.net/websites/%2.whmcs-templates\.net [NC]

Comment: @user2314536 I saw a little bit of mistakes on my codes.. It's now fixed, and you could try it again if you wish.

Comment: Thanks alot it works now :) wish there was something i can do to show you how thankful i am :)

Comment: @user2314536: To show your thank you can (and you should) mark either of these 2 answers as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, I can manage this! Could you please try these *.htaccess* directives AGAIN:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.net$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://domain.net/websites/%2 [P]
```

It will rewrite ***$whatever***.domain.net into *domain.net/websites/**$whatever***.

NOW if it's suppose to be ***$whatever***.domain.net into *domain.net/websites/**$whatever**.domain.net* then you could try this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.net$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://domain.net/websites/%2.domain.net [P]
```

Or maybe this code below is what you've wanted in the future:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain\.net$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.net/websites/%2.domain.net/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
X-Forwarded-Host
/n :(

Comment: Oops i made a huge mistake, its supposed to be It will rewrite $whatever.domain.net into domain.net/websites/$whatever.domain.net

Comment: Im getting 404 error pages, again its suppose to be $whatever.domain.net into domain.net/websites/$whatever.domain.net sorry i dont know much about htaccess

Comment: If i change the last $2 to $1 im getting the /webistes directory index of

Comment: None of those worked Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit. http://demo.whmcs-templates.net/
suppose to show without the new url being shown:
http://demo.whmcs-templates.net/websites/demo.whmcs-templates.net/

Comment: @user2314536 I saw a little bit of mistakes on my codes.. And it's now fixed, and you could even check it again if you wish.